# React.js fetch method on my api is not working?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, fetch, seeding

I am trying to do a simple fetch request from a database hosted on a local server and also I am connected to mongodb in the backend, it seems like something is going wrong with my fetch method. I am getting Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
and  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

```
    function App() {


  const [state, setState]= useState({
    track: '',
    artist:'',
    album:'',
    year: 1990
  }
  )

  // const [token, setToken] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
   
      
    async function getData(){
      const track = await fetch('https://localhost:3001/api/music')
     .then(res => res.json());
      console.log(track)
      
      setState(track)
      // console.log(res)
    }
getData();

  },[])

also this is my route&controller functions

router.get('/', musicCtrl.index)

controller:

function index(req, res){
    Music.find({}, function(err, music){
        res.status(200).json(music)

    })
}

mongo connection

 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const musicSchema = new Schema({
    track: String,
    artist: String,
    album: String,
    year: Number

}, {timestamps:true});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Music', musicSchema);
```

any help please ?!

Comment: Also you have the wrong path . The path in your router.get is `/` instead of `/api/music` ??

Comment: I changed it and I am still getting the same result

Comment: You are mixing async and await with then and catch . Use one . Remove the await before your fetch and also const track . You code has to be just fetch().then(res => res.json()).then(track => setTrack(track)) . You need to add 2 then blocks as I have mentioned here .

Comment: yeah that did not work as well, it keeps telling me track is not defined!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using HTTPS in the fetch url.

Change

```
const track = await fetch('https://localhost:3001/api/music')
```

to

```
const track = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/music')
```

The `getData` function is also mixing `await` and `.then`. Change it to :-

```
async function getData(){
  const track = await fetch('https://localhost:3001/api/music')
  console.log(track.json())
  setState(track.json())
}
```

Comment: thanks, changed it as well but it's still not working, Getting the same error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch"

Comment: Ok, so it fixed the `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error though? Also, can you describe WHERE the error is being thrown

Comment: now it's : GET http://localhost:3001/api/music net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
at js 26        const track = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/music')

Comment: also uncaught(in promise) typeerror : failed to fetch at 32 whic is the " }" at the end of the function. I feel it might be the fact that I seeded a database but maybe I am not referring to it correctly in the backend maybe. so I created a seed.js file in the root directory, var MusicData = require('../seed') i feel like this is wrong I am requring it from inside a file inside a folder on the root directory

Comment: Have you tried going to that URL in your browser? From that, it seems as if the backend isn't responding.

Comment: what do you mean by going go the URL in browser ?!

Comment: Simply type http://localhost:3001/api/music in a browser tab.

Comment: it fetches the information I added to the mongodb on the screen

Comment: on case you had the time here is my github for the backend https://github.com/moeabraham/proj3-backend

Comment: and the foreend is https://github.com/moeabraham/proj3

Comment: thanks man alot, I updated the code but I am still getting an error, a different one src/App.js
  Line 26:22:  'getData' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Comment: We should end this off. Push it to the repo, I'll take a look :)

Comment: I just pushed them to the repo, thanks man